# Post request with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Hi I'm trying to make a post request with Alamofire using instructions from GitHub. Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my code, because new data doesn't appear in json ? Here is my VC code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

private struct Constants {

    static let jsonURL3 = "https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/f31670d2-11bf-11e8-8318-7b18a50c9bd0"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let params = [
        "firstname": "Ivan",
        "lastname": "Nikulin"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(Constants.jsonURL3, method: .post, parameters: params)

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `responseJSON` for your call, you have only done the first part:

```
Alamofire.request(Constants.jsonURL3, method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON { response in
    print(response.result.value)
}
```

Secondly this is a `get` request, so change `method` from `post` to `get` (as I have done in my example).

This will print out the following:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x60c0008371a0>(
{
    firstname = Leo;
    lastname = Messi;
},
{
    firstname = Cristiano;
    lastname = Ronaldo;
}
)
)
```

**Update:**
You can´t post to that URL, you´ll get **405 Method Not Allowed**. If you want to post values you need to create/find an API or URL that allow that, that link is not for that purpose.

Comment: I tried it but' when check my json in browser it is still the same nothing changed

Comment: In your browser? Check your output window in Xcode and you´ll see that it prints out Leo and Cristiano.

Comment: Yes it is, but how i can add new object to json with this url [link](https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/f31670d2-11bf-11e8-8318-7b18a50c9bd0) ? When i change method from .get to .post it doesn't add new data to server.

Answer (score 0):

You created a request object of type `DataRequest` but did not fire it.
You need to call `responseJSON` on that object to get a response.
Here is example from your code

```
let request = Alamofire.request(Constants.jsonURL3, method: .post, parameters: params)
request.responseJSON { (response) in
    print(response.result.value)
}
```